# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied Jupyter notebook on Windows 10 with proxy

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to use jupyter notebook with Python 3.7 on Windows10 for work and am running behind my office network proxy. I was able to run the notebook all fine till a few days ago. Now it keeps showing that the kernel is dead whenever I open the notebook. I get this error to be specific:

[image]

```
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\shreeya.mody\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write
    with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\shreeya.mody\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-0068da95-ca03-4be1-b2c0-4814f6f887f3.json'
```

**What I have tried**

- I have exhausted all the solutions online but nothing so far has worked for me
- Checked permission for files. Looks correct to me
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda multiple times
- Installed anaconda on a work VM to duplicate the error but it works fine there which makes me think that the error is connected to the kernel files somehow that I cannot point at.
- Started notebook from Anaconda Prompt

I want to work on Jupyter notebook on my local machine but no solution I have come across works for me.

Comment: I did:
 
```conda clean -tipsy```

```conda uninstall jupyter```

```conda install jupyter```

and the error went away. Still trying to figure out why this solved the problem.

Comment: I was facing the same issue in my PC, but the solution you suggested does work !

Answer (score 1):

The command line commands from the comments help:

```
conda clean -tipsy
conda uninstall jupyter
conda install jupyter
```

But after the lines the conda environment is almost completely empty. In my case I needed to install numpy and pandas libraries.